# Не могу подключиться к бд Oracle из модуля cx_Oracle на яп Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-oracle

Стоит задача подключиться к БД. Есть TNS

```
dbnuberone=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=np-dbnuberone)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER=default)
      (SERVICE_NAME=sdbnuberone)
    )
  )
```

логин/пароль vip_dbnuberone/password

пытаюсь создать коннект

```
myconnection  = cx_Oracle.connect("vip_dbnuberone/password@'dbnuberone")
```

возвращается ошибка cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

вопрос: как мне прописать коннект исходя из TNS?

Answer (score 0):

```
import cx_Oracle


dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(
    'localhost',
    '1521',
    service_name='sdbnuberone'
)

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(
    user='vip_dbnuberone',
    password='password',
    dsn=dsn
```